# Nativescript error while install

Tags: javascript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

While installing native script, I always get this error while executing this command:

```
npm i -g nativescript
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsYG9.png).

Comment: Did you tried in admin mode? Check the node version.(Latest LTS version) and Not latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to start clean and redo the installation:

`npm remove nativescript -g`

`npm cache clear`

`npm install nativescript -g`